# SSH tunneling when all connections are password protected

Tags: port, forwarding, openssh, tunneling

I've looked for several scenarios of SSH tunneling over here, 
but none of them worked for me. My schema is like this:
Laptop ------> gateway ------> remote.
Pretty common case, but the connection between gateway ----> remote is also password protected. I need my application (NX player though) to connect to remote via port 22.
I can login to gateway via ssh and then login to remote (with different user/password), so it should be possible to do what I want, just not sure how. I'm using openssh in laptop/gateway.

Comment: What's wrong with ` ssh -L 8080:remote:22 gateway`? Please show what you have tried and why it is not working as expected. Your question is not full clear.

Comment: Definitely did the trick... I though that because the gateway ----> remote is secured I need to tell to the gateway how to connect to remote.

Comment: My proposal is to start ssh session with port redirection like `ssh -L 8080:remote:22 gateway` then connect to gateway using `localhost` as host and `8080` as port. If you already tried this solution, specify error you got?

Answer (score 0):

make sure sshd running on gateway support port forwarding.

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

`AllowTcpForwarding yes`